# код работает слишком долго, не получается ускорить

Tags: python, алгоритм, палиндромы

я написала код по задаче

```
В летнем лагере периодически подводится статистика и самые успешные 
участники смены награждаются. Чаще всего награждают школьников, 
решивших наибольшее число задач в каждой параллели, однако иногда 
хочется разбавить скучную статистику решения задач чем-то более 
интересным.

Например, можно выбрать какую-то строку s
из строчных латинских букв, после чего попросить каждого школьника 
выбрать некоторую ее подстроку, после чего наградить тех, кто выбрал 
самые палиндромные подстроки.

Подстрокой строки называется любая последовательность ее подряд идущих
символов, иными словами, любой ее отрезок. Палиндромность строки 
равна количеству ее подстрок, являющихся палиндромами, то есть 
читающихся одинаково слева направо и справа налево.

Всего в смене n школьников, и i-й школьник выбрал подстроку, 
занимающую символы с li-го по ri-й включительно. Определите для 
каждого школьника палиндромность выбранной им строки. Иными словами,
для каждого i найдите количество пар (x,y)таких, что li≤x≤y≤ri и
отрезок sс-го по y-й символ включительно является палиндромом.
```

Мой код:

```py
def c(q):
    l=0
    r=-1
    s="$#"+"#".join(q)+"#"
    n=len(s)
    p=[0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        k=1 if i>r else min (p[l+r-i], r-i+1)
        while (i+k<n and i-k>=0 and s[i+k]==s[i-k]):
            k+=1
        p[i]=k
        if (i+k-1>r):
            l=i-k+1
            r=i+k-1
    return (sum([x//2 for x in p]))

ans=[]
s=input()
n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n): 
    l, r=map(int, input().split()) 
    q=s[l-1:r]
    ans.append(c(q))
 
print(*ans)
```

[(взяла первую часть с функцией с этого же форума)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132451/)

Но он **работает слишком долго** (превышен лимит времени на 7 тесте), я не знаю, как его ускорить... Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Можно попробовать по-простому - изначально преобразовать строку с `#` и использовать удвоенные индексы. Вдруг этого хватит....

Comment: не очень поняла о чем вы, можете пожалуйста отправить реализацию

Comment: запустите свой код с профилированием python -m cProfile -s time euler_7.py 10001     https://habr.com/ru/companies/vk/articles/202832/  посмотрите слабые места.

Answer (score 1):

Вы каждый раз строите новую строку для каждого запроса, преобразуете её с `#` и выделяете массив `p`. В принципе, поскольку алгоритм Манакера работает за линейное время, асимптотически получается сложность равной сумме длин запросов, однако при этом многократное выделение памяти приводит к увеличению времени работы в несколько раз.

Достаточно один раз обработать исходную строку, получить максимальные радиусы палиндромов, центрированных в точке `i` (это массив `p`, если я ничего не путаю), и для каждого запроса пройти интервала `l..r`, оценивая минимум из радиуса палиндрома на каждом индексе и разниц с краями. Сложность получается опять же пропорциональной сумме длин запросов, но только арифметика, без выделений памяти.

Если ограничения задачи позволяют (а вы их не описали) - этого может хватить для решения. Иначе нужно придумывать какую-то нетривиальную декомпозицию для хранения и быстрой оценки палиндромов на отрезках.